# How can I stop Safari putting a magnifying glass image in my <input type="search"> field?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, css

I have a textbox (searchbox) coded as follows

```
<input type="search" id="searchKeywords" name="searchKeywords" value="" maxlength="50">
```

The same does not appear fine in Safari: it has a background image.

But the main issue, according to me, is because of some default style:

```
-webkit-appearance: searchfield;
```

I found this using the Safari Developer tools.

How can I override the same?

I have already tried using;

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
```

and using `!important` as well...

But does not seem to be getting overridden.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: have you find a hack for that block? look for -webkit-appearance propertie's hacks for safari in google.

Comment: I did try finding that...But so far, no luck with that..

Comment: Have you tried putting a `background-image: none !important` attribute on it?

Comment: Why say type="search" if you don't want to let the browser do its default formatting on it?

Comment: agreed with @nnnnnn. The whole point of `type='search'` is to tell the browser to render it as a search field. There's no other difference in functionality with normal `type='text'` other than that.

Comment: There is a difference. input[type="search"] dispatches the "search" events whenever a user hits Enter. Additionally, if the element has the "incremental" attribute, the "search" events are dispatched as the user modifies the input (with a slight delay.) The "search" event is also dispatched when the user clicks the cross at the right of the editbox (for LTR) to clear the input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check out http://Formalize.me it is a great little package that manipulates and standardizes form objects. That being said it looks like it uses:

```
input[type=search] { -webkit-appearance: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the browser to style it as a search field you'll probably have to use `type="text"` instead, just like this site does.

Comment: Even though `type="text"` are styled in some ways, too, but yeah.